# Project Tango strange rotation visualisation

Tags: 3d-reconstruction, google-project-tango

I am working on 3D reconstruction with tango. Our system is quite similar to KinectFusion, which uses voxel representation, but use Tango as tracker. Left image (in video linked below) is rendered by Raycast at current pose (given by tango) in real time. Raw pose converted by GetOC2OWMat() as in code examples, in addition sign of tx and rx are flipped to cope with our system. Everything works fine except ration in Z axis, which changes angle in rendered image. I guess coordinate system conversion is not done properly, but depth integration is working if no Z rotation is involved. I have also checked det(R) is always 1.﻿

[Video](https://youtu.be/9SPrjNd_H4k)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry that I just find the place where things goes wrong. When the image is displayed with opengl, the rendered gl size does not have same aspect ratio as Raycasting image.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are not factoring in intrinsics -  have you accounted for camera and device IMU frames ?  You need these to fully re-establish original viewpoint, i.e. both camera and device imu frame matrices need to be multiplied in to your stack

Comment: Hi, I have figured out that it's because of the gl rendering aspect ratio does not match image aspect ratio. Do you think generating depth map from point cloud should consider radial distortion in intrinsic matrix(does this improve result a lot?). It seems to me tango tracking is not that ideal, especially in Z axis(compared to point to plane icp combined with IMU correction)

Comment: Haven't had to mess with lens distortion yet, however the device and camera offsets are necessary to reconstruct original view. Yes, Z axis should be viewed as a statistically accurate guess over time, not a laser rangefinder.  That's the first order problem.  The second order problem is drift - angular offset in a given frame is accurate, but cumulative angular offset has drift, which brings in more error.  O Joy.

Comment: Has that been factored into GetOC2OWMat() in Google's sample code(I think both frame are mentioned during conversion)?

Comment: Hi Mark, I am wondering if there is a good way to synchronise coloured and depth frame. As depth frame comes at 5fps and colour at 25fps. Their time difference is pretty close to 1/25s, under which condition fast(not that fast) movement will cause wrong mapping between colour and depth frame.

Comment: I've never seen them line up exactly - I don't think it is supposed to be possible, for the color frame at the time of depth acquisition is going to have the mantis ir data in it - I posted a picture of a grab to the google+ page a long time ago - I just select the image that has the least absolute timestamp differential - works fine for my cases so far

Answer (score 0):

Do you program with Java/C/Unity? I'm curious because my device has problems with the camera data and you seem to capture it without problems. I am quite sure it's a bug but I would like to make sure it really is one.

Comment: I am using C api. It's pretty tricky to get colour image right because it's a nested pointer and have to recursively memcpy pointer data inside.